This manga is comedy action.The ml is rich and cursed with something on his birthday and ask fl for help who is a high school student. Is slight adult
This manga is fantasy action. ml is rich and cursed with something on his birthday and ask fl for help who is a high school student. Is slight adult

Where did you get this image from?

I took screenshot of it during the time when I was reading it on wecomics
